# How to run/use Validation while using Cdbcommandbuilder::createMultipleInsertCommand()

Tags: php, yii

Yii 1.1.14

I am using `CDbCommandBuilder::createMultipleInsertCommand()` to create a multiple insert CDbCommand. But how can I run validation before saving it?
For single insert commands, the validation is done inside `CActiveRecord::save()` method (I think).

```
// Controller

if (isset($_POST['ProductBrand'])) {
    $model->attributes = $_POST['ProductBrand'];

    if ($model->saveRows())
        $this->redirect(array('indexBrand'));

}

// Model


public function saveRows()
{
    $builder = Yii::app()->db->schema->commandBuilder;
    $names = explode(', ', $this->attributes['name']);
    $type_id = $this->attributes['type_id'];
    $attributes = array();
    foreach ($names as $name) :
        $attributes[] = array('name' => $name, 'type_id' => $type_id);
    endforeach;
    $command = $builder->createMultipleInsertCommand('vwa_product_brand',
        $attributes);
    if ($command->execute()) :
        return TRUE;
    endif;
    return FALSE;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yii provide the option to call functions before and after save in model. So you can call your custom validation function in beforesave functions.

Another method to call validation in controller, follow the below syntax

> ModelName::model()->validate();

For more details, refer below links

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#beforeSave-detail

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/26637-solved-cactiveform-validate-on-ajax-submit/

Comment: Yep, that worked. Wondering why it doesnt showed up in google.